# Water pump's O-ring a little smaller?

Tags: water-pump, seal

The original size of a new water pump rubber O-ring is 3mm diameter(thickness)and 80mm inner diameter.
When i disassembled the water pump for other task(the water pump is fine),i have noticed that the o-ring is flattened,so i need to replace it with a new one.I have a new o-ring that has 3mm thickness,but the inner diameter is 78mm(2mm less than the original one).Will those less 2mm affect the sealing of the water-pump?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you supply more details?  Make, model, and year of the vehicle as well as the engine option in it.  A photo of the old and new water pumps and the o-rings would be helpful too.

Comment: Prob of course is when you stretch that extra 2 mms, it will reduce the width of the o-ring. How much? can really tell. If it was linear (double length stretch == half width) then you may ends up making a 2.9 ish width o-ring. That 10th mm may not matter, depending on the depth of the grooves it fit into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount the o-ring will be stretch is going to be minimal, but it will be some. 2mm is not that much overall, so I think it should work for your needs.

What you have to be aware of is in order for the o-ring to seal in the first place, there has to be a "squish" put upon it. This means both sides of where the o-ring sits has to push into the o-ring itself. If this doesn't happen, it won't seal at all. If there isn't enough squish, it won't seal, or seal very well. You need to check how much the o-ring pops up over the top of the groove on each side. If you believe there is enough o-ring there to overcome the groove and sit well against the other side so there will be plenty of squish on the o-ring, it should be in good shape. If there doesn't appear to going to be enough squish of the o-ring, you'll want to hold off and get a true replacement.

Obviously this isn't going to be optimal, but realistically, sometimes you've got to do what you've got to do.